# Some data is not being read from Firebase database Swift 3

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a database in firebase that looks like this [image]
I am trying to get the url given the key. However, I am only able to get the url for a few of these keys, the rest return nil? I don't see a pattern as to why some keys would return the value I am looking for and some dont? This is the code I am using

```
static func getProfilePictureURL(imageID key: String, completionHandler: @escaping (_ return: String?, _ error: String?) -> Void){
        databaseReference.child("userSelfies").child(userIDGlobal).observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
            // Get user value

        let value = snapshot.value as? [String: Any]
        print(value!["150575773394828"])

        if let url = value?[key] {
            print("url",url)
            //completionHandler(url, nil)
        }

    }) { (error) in
        print(error.localizedDescription)
        completionHandler(nil,  error.localizedDescription)

    }
}
```

I have tried everything, and yes the page is reloaded so the data definitely is there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So it looks like the function `getProfilePictureURL` needs only get the image for the one `imageID key`, yes? What happens if you query just the key you're looking for?

```
static func getProfilePictureURL(imageID key: String, completionHandler: @escaping (_ return: String?, _ error: String?) -> Void){
        databaseReference.child("userSelfies/\(userIDGlobal)/\(key)).observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
            // Get user value

        let url = snapshot.value as? String
        print("url",url)
        //completionHandler(url, nil)

    }) { (error) in
        print(error.localizedDescription)
        completionHandler(nil,  error.localizedDescription)

    }
}
```

Comment: Seems to work with some modifications, not sure why tho

Comment: I can't use the as? String but I have to use String(describing:) instead

Comment: Cool! Feel free to edit the answer to show how it worked for you.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so the problem was that the path to child was too 'deep'. What Jen suggested was almost right, but they end of the path, the (key), should not be there. Because the snapshot.value is returned as as NSDictionary, with key value pairs, what I should have done is cast the snapshot.value as? [String: AnyObject], and then unwrapped and used that value with subscript [key] to get the value I want. 8 hours of searching and experimenting and i've finally figured swift firebase database out...